# How to get the role of the author of a message with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am looking with help for a problem I am having with discord.js. I am making a discord bot, and I am trying to detect if the author of a message has a specific role or not using an if statement.
I am using discord.js 12.0.2. I have tried both ways below:

```
message.member.roles.some(r => r.name === 'Admin')

message.member.roles.has('Admin')
```

However, I get an error message saying that 'some' is not a function. The same thing happens with 'has'. Looking through documentation and outdated stack overflow posts, I couldn't find any other way to do it.
help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `member.roles.cache` as per [discord.js v12 documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions)?

```
message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'Admin')

message.member.roles.cache.has('roleID')
```